# Import error in Python 2

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to do this python programming for the class - and I am getting stuck even before I can get started.

Thus far, this is what I have installed:

python 2.7.3,

Enthought Canopy, which includes numpy, scipy and matplotlib, all for python 2.

When I try to execute the code (which is: **import random, math, pylab**) it throws error at the pylab. It keeps telling me this: *ImportError: cannot import name multiarray **

And this error is reproducible from both Windows Powershell, IDLE and Canopy IDE. This symptom persists even after I installed matplotlib separately.

I don't even know what I am doing wrong or how I should fix this. There is not much thought process involved in this IMPORT statement, right? Any idea? Any one? Nobody seems to have this problem that I have either so I don't know what's up with that.

The code is this:

```
import random, math, pylab

def direct_pi(N):
    n_hits = 0
    for i in range(N):
        x, y = random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0), random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0)
        if x ** 2 + y ** 2 < 1.0:
            n_hits += 1
    return n_hits

n_runs = 500
n_trials_list = []
sigmas = []
for poweroftwo in range(4, 13):
    n_trials = 2 ** poweroftwo
    sigma = 0.0
    for run in range(n_runs):
        pi_est = 4.0 * direct_pi(n_trials) / float(n_trials)
        sigma += (pi_est - math.pi) ** 2
    sigmas.append(math.sqrt(sigma/(n_runs)))
    n_trials_list.append(n_trials)

pylab.plot(n_trials_list, sigmas, 'o')
pylab.gca().set_xscale('log')
pylab.gca().set_yscale('log')
pylab.xlabel('n_trials')
pylab.ylabel('$\sigma$')
pylab.title('Direct sampling: Standard deviation $\sigma$ as a function of n_trials')
pylab.savefig('direct_sampling_statistical_error.png')
pylab.show()
```

Trace from Enthought suite:

```
C:\Users\Friedrich\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, glob, loc)
    195             else:
    196                 filename = fname
--> 197             exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
    198     else:
    199         def execfile(fname, *where):

D:\Stat_mech\W1L1\direct_pi_multirun.py in <module>()
----> 1 import random, math, pylab
      2 
      3 def direct_pi(N):
      4     n_hits = 0
      5     for i in range(N):

D:\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pylab.py in <module>()
----> 1 from matplotlib.pylab import *
      2 import matplotlib.pylab
      3 __doc__ = matplotlib.pylab.__doc__

D:\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in <module>()
    154 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    155 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 156 from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like
    157 from matplotlib.compat import subprocess
    158 

D:\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py in <module>()
     26 from weakref import ref, WeakKeyDictionary
     27 
---> 28 import numpy as np
     29 import numpy.ma as ma
     30 

d:\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>()

d:\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py in <module>()

d:\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py in <module>()

d:\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py in <module>()

d:\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>()

ImportError: cannot import name multiarray
```

Comment: can you edit your post to show you code properly formatted and the _full_ trace back?

Comment: Does `import numpy` work from the command line?  I suspect that you have a fouled numpy installation. Did you try to install nupmy outside of enthought?

Comment: I was getting suspicious about that because whenever I tried installing NumPy, I would always get the pop-up window that says:

`Executing numpy installer failed`

And this is with the program run as admin. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: And... the idea was to install the complete suite of SciPy, NumPy and matlibplot altogether without having to install each one separately - I ended up trying anyway. And I tried uninstalling Enthought and installing NumPy alone. Still does not work.

Comment: As the last resort, I uninstalled python 2.7.3, reinstalled it and tried installing NumPy. Now, NumPy does not even recognize the Python 2.7.3 I have. I have to wonder just what the hell is going on.

Comment: What OS, if I may ask? - Sorry, obviously windows. What do you use to install these modules?

Comment: msi, executables, you name it. I tried it all - and it still does not work.

Comment: And to my surprise, it is working as intended now. All I did was to turn it off and let it sleep for good 5 hours. [I did cold boot before, but I don't know if keeping it off for a certain amount of time would do the magic.]